# Disable clicking on tabPanel in TabContainer

Tags: c#, asp.net, tabpanel, tabcontainer

I want to disable clicking and going from one tabPanel to another. Like here http://www.eldan.co.il/en/  the user can't select another step. I tried something like this

`if (Tabs.ActiveTabIndex == 0)
{
    Tabs.Tabs[1].Enabled = false;
}`

but it hides the tab...

Comment: If `Tabs` is the TabContainer `Tabs.Tabs[1].Enabled = false` should disable the second TabPanel. To hide a TabPanel you would use the `Visible` property.

Comment: I don't want to hide anything, only disable second tab. But by default enabled = false is equal to visible = false.

Comment: what i wanted to say: i cannot reproduce your described behaviour.

Comment: go to http://www.eldan.co.il/en/

Answer (score 0):

I found something that helped me.

...prevent switching to the tab on click depending on form validation

Returning false in the tabs select handler prevents the clicked tab from becoming selected.

`$('#example').tabs({
    select: function(event, ui) {
        var isValid = ... // form validation returning true or false
        return isValid;
    }
});`